# Play framework 2: form mapping from Java classes

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.2

I have Play2 app with Scala and data model generated from XSD with JAXB. So, it's a bunch of quite complexed classes (Java, of course, not case classes) with more than 250 attributes as a whole. And my goal is creating of CRUD GUI for all that stuff.

As I know, Java version of Play uses Spring data binder for wrapping existing class to the form. And in Scala one should describe forms manually like that:

```
val computerForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> optional(longNumber),
    "name" -> nonEmptyText,
    "introduced" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    "discontinued" -> optional(date("yyyy-MM-dd")),
    "company" -> optional(longNumber)
  )(Computer.apply)(Computer.unapply)
)
```

So here's my question: is there a handy way to wrap my whole model to the form without painful manual description of every attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You have to manually define the form's representation

Comment: It might be worth writing a script/macro/something else to generate the `Form` mapping "semi-automatically" given that XSD's have a habit of getting changed...